# string references behaving strangley in javascript closure

Tags: javascript, closures

I want the following code to print "cat", but instead it prints "bat"

```
var a = "cat";
x = function(){
  var b = a;
  console.log(b);
}
a = "bat";
x();
```

what can I do to get
the inner function to work the way I want it to? Is there a way to do it without allocating any more space?

Answer (score 1):

It is because the variable a is reassigned to "cat" before the execution of the function x. Hence till you call x() , the variable b will be undeclared. During the declaration happens , the value of a is "bat".

Answer (score 0):

at this below code snippet

```
x = function(){
  var b = a;
  console.log(b);
}
```

you have just defined a anonymous function which binds an outer score variable `a` resulting in `a closure`. So its bound with its outer scope. So at the time of execution of function of `x` at

```
x();
```

a's value in global scope is `"bat"` resulting the anonimous function to return you `"bat"`.

This might make it more clear

```
var a = "cat";
x = function(){
  var b = a;
  alert(b);
}
a = "bat";
x();//alerts bat
a = "wow";
x();//alerts wow
a = "im bound to the outer scope";
x();//alerts im bound to the outer scope
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixes the issue I was having:

```
var a = "cat";
function copyCatBuilder(animal){
    return function(){ console.log(animal)};
}
x = copyCatBuilder(a);
a = "bat";

x();
```

The program now outputs "cat"